# MongoDB aggregates (time & avg)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wonder if it's possible to do an average over a MongoDb time series aggregate. For instance, an aggregate that gives the average temp for every minute.

My data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57fbebf99929a71d305e2bb2",
    "temp": 23.77,
    "dateTime": "2016-10-10T19:28:57.923Z",
    "_dateTime": 1476127737000
  },
  {
    "_id": "57fbebfa9929a71d305e2bb3",
    "temp": 27.16,
    "dateTime": "2016-10-10T19:28:58.838Z",
    "_dateTime": 1476127738000
  },
  {
    "_id": "57fbebff9929a71d305e2bb4",
    "temp": 31.93,
    "dateTime": "2016-10-10T19:29:03.848Z",
    "_dateTime": 1476127743000
  }
]
```

The code (javascript) looks like this so far..

```
 var results = temperatures.aggregate(
     [
        { $project : { "timeSpan" : {$add : [new Date(0),"$_dateTime"] } } },
        { $project : {  "minuteRead" : { $minute : "$timeSpan" }} }, 
        { 
             $group : { 
                _id : {minuteRead : "$minuteRead" },
                count : { $sum : 1 } 
            } 
        }
     ], 
     function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
 );
```

With the output of:

```
[ { _id: { minuteRead: 30 }, count: 7 },
  { _id: { minuteRead: 29 }, count: 12 },
  { _id: { minuteRead: 28 }, count: 2 } ]
```

But what I'd like to have is:

```
[ { _id: { minuteRead: 30 }, avgTemp: 17.6 },
  { _id: { minuteRead: 29 }, avgTemp: 18.3 },
  { _id: { minuteRead: 28 }, avgTemp: 20.1 } ]
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "$avg" would do the trick

```
$group : { 
                _id : {minuteRead : "$minuteRead" },
                avgTemp : { $avg :"$temp" } 
            }
```

Comment: I thought so too, but it seems the $temp values is not accessable. Do I need to add it in a $project?

   ` [ { _id: { minuteRead: 30 }, avgTemp: null },`
    `{ _id: { minuteRead: 29 }, avgTemp: null },`
    `{ _id: { minuteRead: 28 }, avgTemp: null } ]`

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
temperatures.aggregate(
        [
           { $project: { temp:'$temp', "timeSpan": { $add: [new Date(0), "$_dateTime"] } }},
           { $project: { "timestamp": { $minute: "$timeSpan" }, temp:'$temp' } },
           {
               $group: {
                   _id: { minuteRead: "$timestamp" },
                    avgTemp : { $avg :"$temp" }
               }
           }
        ],
        function (err, result) {
            if (err)
                console.log("ERROR " + err);
            else
                console.log(result);
        }
    );
```